# Is it good practice to assign an instantiated class to a static property in the same class?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, static

I have code that was written by someone else that goes like this:

On a ViewModel:

```
public static ACertainViewModel Default { get; private set; }
```

On the same ViewModel's constructor:

```
    public ACertainViewModel()
    {
        Default = this;
    }
```

On a method in the class that ACertainViewModel implements:

```
        if (ACertainViewModel.Default != null && ACertainViewModel.Default.property != null)
        //do something to property
```

Seems to work, but it doesn't really feel right. Can something go wrong here?

Comment: Is this to implement a singleton or mark an object as the first one created (thus default)?

Answer (score 4):

Having a static default instance like that is fine.

This particular implementation though is not fine. If you have a static default instance, I would expect there to be *one* static default instance. As shown, this changes the static default instance every time you make one of these (and leaves it null until then).

It would be better to do this in a static constructor, initializer, or getter so that you only have one, and it is always there when you ask for it.